In Rust, what is the best way to have application state that is mutable and shared across threads
In my application I have some shared mutable state that is accessed and updated by multiple threads.
The application state has structure, where some entities own lists of other entities.
The business logic that sits on top of this model needs to find and update entities, add and remove entities from lists, and generally manipulate the model in multiple threads.

This is the solution that I came up with, but maybe someone else can think of a more concise, more functional, or more efficient way to do this.
use std::{
    collections::HashMap, 
    hash::Hash, 
    marker::PhantomData, 
    sync::{
        Arc, RwLock
    }
};

/// All model entities should implement the Entity trait so that we can add them to a HashMap
pub trait Entity<K> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone { 
    fn key(self: &Self) -> K;
}

/// Represents a thread-safe sharable reference to a model entity
pub struct EntityRef<K, E> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone, E: Entity<K>{ 
    entity: Arc<E>,
    phantom_data: PhantomData<K>,
}

impl<K, E> EntityRef<K, E> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone, E: Entity<K> {
    pub fn new(entity: E) -> Self { Self { entity: Arc::new(entity), phantom_data: PhantomData }}
    pub fn copy(entity_ref: &EntityRef<K, E>) -> Self { Self { entity: entity_ref.entity.clone(), phantom_data: PhantomData} }
    pub fn entity(self: &Self) -> &Arc<E> { &self.entity }
    pub fn key(self: &Self) -> K { self.entity.key() }
}

impl<K, E> Clone for EntityRef<K, E> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone, E: Entity<K> {
    fn clone(self: &Self) -> Self { Self::copy(self) }
}

impl<K, E> std::ops::Deref for EntityRef<K, E> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone, E: Entity<K> {
    type Target = E;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target { &self.entity }
}

/// Represents a thread-safe sharable reference to a list of model entities (for example a list of Ledgers)
pub struct EntityList<K, E> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone, E: Entity<K> {
    entities: RwLock<HashMap<K, EntityRef<K, E>>>,
}

impl<K, E> EntityList<K, E> where K: Eq + Hash + Clone, E: Entity<K> {
    pub fn new() -> Self { 
        Self { entities: RwLock::new(HashMap::new()) }
    }
    
    pub fn from_iter_ref(entities: impl Iterator<Item = EntityRef<K, E>>) -> Self {
        let entities = entities.map(|entity_ref| (entity_ref.key(), entity_ref.clone())).collect();
        Self { entities: RwLock::new(entities) }
    }
    
    pub fn from_iter(entities: impl Iterator<Item = E>) -> Self {
        let entities = entities.map(|entity| (entity.key(), EntityRef::new(entity))).collect();
        Self { entities: RwLock::new(entities) }
    }

    pub fn insert(self: &Self, entity: E) -> Option<EntityRef<K, E>> {
        let mut entities = self.entities.write().unwrap();
        entities.insert(entity.key(), EntityRef::new(entity))
    }
    
    pub fn insert_ref(self: &Self, entity_ref: EntityRef<K, E>) -> Option<EntityRef<K, E>> {
        let mut entities = self.entities.write().unwrap();
        entities.insert(entity_ref.key(), entity_ref)
    }
    
    pub fn remove(self: &Self, key: &K) -> Option<EntityRef<K, E>> {
        let mut entities = self.entities.write().unwrap();
        entities.remove(key)
    }
    
    pub fn get(self: &Self, k: &K) -> Option<EntityRef<K, E>> {
        Some(self.entities.read().unwrap().get(k)?.clone())
    }

    /// Enumerates all of the entities in this list finding the first one that matches the
    /// supplied predicate
    pub fn find(self: &Self, predicate: impl Fn(&EntityRef<K, E>) -> bool) -> Option<EntityRef<K, E>> {
        match self.entities.read().unwrap().iter().find(|&item| predicate(item.1)) {
            Some((_k, entity_ref)) => Some(entity_ref.clone()),
            None => None,
        }
    }

    /// Constructs and returns a vector containing a snapshot of the current entity keys.
    pub fn keys(self: &Self) -> Vec<K> {
        self.entities.read().unwrap().keys().map(|k|k.clone()).collect()
    }

    /// Constructs and returns a vector containing clones of the entities in the list. These clones 
    /// reference the original entities through an Arc
    pub fn values(self: &Self) -> Vec<EntityRef<K, E>> {
        self.entities.read().unwrap().values().map(|entity_ref|entity_ref.clone()).collect()
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests{
    use super::*;

    // The mutable state must be in a separate private struct so that we can protect access
    // through a RwLock
    struct TestEntityState {
        name: String,
    }

    // This is an example of how the model entities are defined. The entity is
    // thread safe but not sharable. To share the entity accross multiple threads
    // it needs to be wrapped in am EntityRef
    pub struct TestEntity {
        id: usize,
        state: RwLock<TestEntityState>,
    }

    impl TestEntity {
        pub fn new(id: usize, name: String) -> Self {
            Self { id, state: RwLock::new(TestEntityState { name }) }
        }

        pub fn id(self: &Self) -> usize{ self.id }
        pub fn name(self: &Self) -> String { self.state.read().unwrap().name.clone() }

        pub fn set_name(self: &Self, name: String) {
            self.state.write().unwrap().name = name;
        }
    }

    impl Entity<usize> for TestEntity { 
        fn key(self: &Self) -> usize { self.id }
    }

    pub struct TestEntityList {
        id: usize,
        test_entities: EntityList<usize, TestEntity>,
    }

    impl TestEntityList {
        pub fn new(id: usize) -> Self {
            Self { id, test_entities: EntityList::new() }
        }

        pub fn test_entities(self: &Self) -> &EntityList<usize, TestEntity> { &self.test_entities }
    }

    impl Entity<usize> for TestEntityList { 
        fn key(self: &Self) -> usize { self.id }
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn thread_safe_sharable_entities() {
        let entity_ref = EntityRef::new(TestEntity::new(1,  String::from("Tester")));

        // Clones of EntityRef refer to the same entity
        let cloned = entity_ref.clone();

        // This might print "Tester" or "Updated" depending on the timing
        std::thread::spawn(move|| println!("{}", cloned.name()));

        // Internally the entity uses a RwLock to prevent updates during reads
        entity_ref.set_name(String::from("Updated"));

        // This will always print "Updated"
        println!("{}:{}", entity_ref.id, entity_ref.name());
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn thread_safe_sharable_lists() {
        let mut list = Vec::new();
        list.push(TestEntity::new(1, String::from("Test 1")));
        list.push(TestEntity::new(2, String::from("Test 2")));
        list.push(TestEntity::new(3, String::from("Test 3")));

        // EntityList needs to be wrapped in Arc to allow thread sharing
        let entity_list = Arc::new(EntityList::from_iter(list.into_iter()));
 
        // Arc must be cloned to move into a thread
        let clone = entity_list.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move|| println!("{}", clone.get(&2).unwrap().name()));

        // Arc must be cloned to move into a thread
        let clone = entity_list.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move|| clone.remove(&3));

        // Because EntityRef is Deref, the syntax is very natural
        for key in entity_list.keys() {
            if let Some(entity) = entity_list.get(&key) {
                println!("{}", entity.name());
            }
        }
        
        if let Some(test1) = entity_list.values().iter().find(|e|e.name() == "Test 1") {
            println!("{}:{}", test1.id, test1.name());
        };
    }

    #[test]
    pub fn entities_containing_lists_of_other_entities() {
        let entity = TestEntityList::new(1);

        entity.test_entities().insert(TestEntity::new(1, String::from("Test 1")));
        entity.test_entities().insert(TestEntity::new(2, String::from("Test 2")));
        entity.test_entities().insert(TestEntity::new(3, String::from("Test 3")));
        
        entity.test_entities().values().iter().for_each(|e| println!("{}", e.name()));

        match entity.test_entities().find(|e|e.name() == "Test 2") {
            Some(entity_ref) => print!("{}", entity_ref.id()),
            None => panic!(),
        }
    }
}

